# stay displaying informations with sessionStorage after refresh

Tags: javascript, timer, session-storage

I made a timer and I would like to keep it running if the user refreshes the page.
I saved informations (secondes and minutes) in sessionStorage, but I have no idea how to keep timer running while user refresh the page.

```
var COUNT_START = 10 * 20 * 60;
var count = COUNT_START;
var playing = false;
var play = document.getElementById('Reservation');
var reset = document.getElementById('annuler');

play.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (empty > 5) {
        $('#count-timer').fadeIn(1000);
        playing = true
    } else {
        $('#title-reservation').text('Signez votre réservation')
    }
});

reset.addEventListener('click', function () {
    playing = false;
    sessionStorage.removeItem('nom_station');
    $('#title-reservation').html('Votre réservation a bien été annulée');
    count = COUNT_START;
});

function countdown() {var COUNT_START = 10 * 20 * 60;
    var count = COUNT_START;
    var playing = false;
    var play = document.getElementById('Reservation');
    var reset = document.getElementById('annuler');

    play.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (empty > 5) {
            $('#count-timer').fadeIn(1000);
            playing = true
        } else {
            $('#title-reservation').text('Signez votre réservation')
        }
    });

    reset.addEventListener('click', function () {
        playing = false;
        sessionStorage.removeItem('nom_station');
        $('#title-reservation').html('Votre réservation a bien été annulée');
        count = COUNT_START;
    });

    function countdown() {
        displayTime();
        if (count === 0) {
            playing = false;
            sessionStorage.removeItem('nom_station');
            $('#title-reservation').text('Votre réservation a expirée');
        } else if (playing) {
            setTimeout(countdown, 100);
            count--;
        } else {
            setTimeout(countdown, 100);
        }
    }

    countdown();

    function displayTime() {
        this.mill = count;
        this.sec = Math.floor(this.mill / 10);
        this.mins = Math.floor(this.sec / 60);
        this.sec -= this.mins * (60);
        this.sec_storage = sessionStorage.setItem('sec_storage', this.sec);
        this.min_storage = sessionStorage.setItem('min_storage', this.mins);
        this.get_sec_storage = sessionStorage.getItem('sec_storage');
        this.get_min_storage = sessionStorage.getItem('min_storage');

        $('#count-timer').text('Votre réservation expire dans : ' + this.get_min_storage + ' minute(s) ' + this.get_sec_storage  + ' seconde(s) ')

    }
    displayTime();
    if (count === 0) {
        playing = false;
        sessionStorage.removeItem('nom_station');
        $('#title-reservation').text('Votre réservation a expirée');
    } else if (playing) {
        setTimeout(countdown, 100);
        count--;
    } else {
        setTimeout(countdown, 100);
    }
}

countdown();

function displayTime() {
    this.mill = count;
    this.sec = Math.floor(this.mill / 10);
    this.mins = Math.floor(this.sec / 60);
    this.sec -= this.mins * (60);
    this.sec_storage = sessionStorage.setItem('sec_storage', this.sec);
    this.min_storage = sessionStorage.setItem('min_storage', this.mins);
    this.get_sec_storage = sessionStorage.getItem('sec_storage');
    this.get_min_storage = sessionStorage.getItem('min_storage');

    $('#count-timer').text('Votre réservation expire dans : ' + this.get_min_storage + ' minute(s) ' + this.get_sec_storage  + ' seconde(s) ')
}
```

If someone can show me how to do that, i'll appreciate a lot !
Thank you :)
Sorry for my english

Comment: When the page is refreshed, declared timeouts are cleared, you need to do achieve this on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to keep the timer running after page refresh, but you can try storing timestamp just before refresh and compare with new timestamp after page is refreshed and reloaded; you can get difference how much time it took to refresh the page. And you can start timer with adding difference in your last stored timer value.